# Observables HotConcat with Max Parallelism

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable, concatenation, reactive

I’m reading time series data from the database, but those datapoints are partitions across different places. So, for example, if there is a 1 Hz data, every 3600 datapoint (for one hour) is stored in a different partition. When I read those datapoints, I have to return them to the user in the correct logical order. So, I have to return the 3600 datapoints for hour 00:00 and then 3600 datapoints for hour 01:00, … until hour 23:00. Naturally, there is a delay in database queries. Let’s say it’s 10 ms for each query. That means that if I do concat, it would have a delay of 24 * 10 ms = 240 ms. What I need is a hot concat with a number of parallelism. I can’t execute all of those queries sequentially and then do a regular concat because the user might want data for 1 year.
Currently, what I have is something like this:

```
public IObservable<int> ReadSensorPartitions( /* Guid sensorId*/)
        {
            return Observable.Create<int>(async o =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    Observable.Range(1, 1000).Subscribe(o);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    o.OnError(e);
                }
            });
        }

        public IObservable<int> ReadSensorData(int partitionNum)
        {
            return Observable.Create<int>(async o =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    Observable.Range(partitionNum*1000, 999).Subscribe(o);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    o.OnError(e);
                }
            });
        }

        public IObservable<int> ConcatObservables(IObservable<IObservable<int>> observables)
        {
            return ReadSensorPartitions().Select(partitionNum => ReadSensorData(partitionNum)).Concat();
        } 

        public async Task TestConcatObservables()
        {
            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            long count = 0;
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            ConcatObservables(ReadSensorPartitions().Select(partitionNum => ReadSensorData(partitionNum)))
                .Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    count++;
                }, ex =>
                {

                }, () =>
                {
                    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
                });
            await taskCompletionSource.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("TestConcatObservables Duration for {0} datapoint(s) is {1} ms", count, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        }
```

for 1 year of data, this would take at least 87.6 seconds. I need something like this

```
public IObservable<int> HotConcatObservables(IObservable<IObservable<int>> observables, int parallelism)
        {

        }
```

If, for example parallelism is set to be 24, then the first 24 reads are immediately all warmed up and buffer. And we return partition 1, then 2, … until 24, once partition 1 is finished streaming, we immediately warm up partition 25. Once partition 2 has finished streaming, we warm up partition 26, etc. All of those datapoints have to be returned in the correct logical order.

I have spent a significant amount of time to do this, but the best that I did (using IConnectableObservable) , is 5 times slower than Merge (even if parallelism is the same number of partitions). Is there anyway. Can this be done efficiently? I really really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: just as a note it is possible for this data to be returned out of order.

Comment: @MatthewWhited doing this you mean?
ReadSensorPartitions().Select(partitionNum => ReadSensorData(partitionNum)).Concat();

Comment: You have no control over the order that each page of data is returned.  You might be better of just using a single stream versus trying to retreive multiple pages of data. Do you need the full resolution of every second for a year of data?  That is over 31 Million data points.

Comment: Even a single day would be over 86 thousand data points.

Comment: "You have no control over the order that each page of data is returned."
they are stored in the database (Apache Cassandra) in order, and the datapoints are retrieved in the correct order for each partition.
And unfortunately, yes, we need all of those data. At times, it's to do a downsample on the fly (but in code), and at times the user just wants the RAW datapoints through a websocket, or other ways

Comment: partitions in the database can reside in different servers. So we've to make one database call for each partition.

Comment: You are not getting my point.  As soon as you async the data sets you do not have control of the order.  if both pages are loaded at the same time it is possible for the CPU to finish and release the second first.  It can even interleave the data.

Comment: aha, I see what you're saying. that's clear now, thank you @MatthewWhited

Comment: I think you might want to look at using [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) for this. It allows you to perform an async fork-join with a configurable degree of concurrency while retaining order. What's more it interops natively with Rx.